# Put a Mark in aspCode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

This is a practical question, i wonder if its possible to put a mark in code to quickly refind the place.

So i'm working in the middle zone of a big ASP page (so debug dot isnt possible) and i have to get any information at the top of the page.. It would be cool to put a mark to come back quicly at the first place..

Thanks to everyone..
(and sorry for my english)

Comment: In fact there is another solution.. ctrl+- replace the cursor at the last position.. (invert is ctrl+maj+-) .  Useful..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> sets a bookmark at the current cursor line.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> - Previous Bookmark

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> - Next Bookmark

Answer (score 3):

Use BookMark.
VisualStudio 2008 -> Edit -> BookMarks -> Toggle BookMark (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>K</kbd>)

You can navigate through bookmarks using Preivous (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and Next(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has bookmarks you can add as markers in the text editors. Then navigate forward/backwards through them.

More details (this week) here: [setting bookmarks](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/zainnab/~3/0PwTJCOETew/setting-bookmarks-vstiptool0047.aspx), [organizing bookmarks](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/zainnab/~3/oOGi8PaMLTo/organizing-bookmarks-vstiptool0048.aspx) and [navigating bookmarks](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/zainnab/~3/gEZy5ESR02I/navigating-bookmarks-vstiptool0049.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing some new code and need to adjust some code located somewhere else, you can also the code you were writing, preferrable with an error (omitting the semicolon for example). This forces you to return to correct the code, plus you can doubleclick on the error in the error list to jump back to where you were.